# Append new text field while clicking a button and remove by clicking button in Laravel 4

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel-4

i have a form  with **two fields** such as **phone**, **email** like below image.

[image: Form layout]

when i click on the **plus** button , i want to append one extra text field in form below the button. and i want to remove the text field when clicking the **minus** button.

dynamically add the fields and set name for unique for that. i need these data to insert into table.

my html code is showed in below..

```
 <div class="RegSpLeft"><input type="text" value="Phone"></div>

 <div class="RegSpRight"> <a href="#"><img src="images/plus.png"></a> <a href="#"><img src="images/minus.png"></a> </div>
```

Comment: You did not ask a question, what exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: For adding textbox you need jQuery or javascript because it's client side changes with out refresh page

Comment: @Jishad is below solution working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you.

```
<div class="RegSpLeft" id="phone">
        <input type="text" value="Phone">
    </div>

    <div class="RegSpRight">
        <a href="#" class="pl">+
        </a>
        <br/>
        <a href="#" class="mi">-
        </a>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('a.pl').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#phone').append('<input type="text" value="Phone">');
        });
        $('a.mi').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($('#phone input').length > 1) {
                $('#phone').children().last().remove();
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: thanks its working ..! but how to dynamically add name for textfield. ?

Comment: need to create input type array